# does parentheses influence in this mysql results?

Tags: sql, mysql

i was trying to run this query:

```
(
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `access_level` > 0) AS `search_subject` WHERE (BINARY `username` = ?))

    UNION

    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `access_level` > 0) AS `search_subject` WHERE (BINARY `username` = ?))
)
LIMIT 5
```

but got an error because of the surrounding parenthesis, just before `LIMIT 5`. `obs: the query is all in a row, i endented it here for better reading. is it allowed in sql?`

the following works fine:

```
(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `access_level` > 0) AS `search_subject` WHERE (BINARY `username` = ?))

UNION

(SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `access_level` > 0) AS `search_subject` WHERE (BINARY `username` = ?))

LIMIT 5
```

my question is: this second version is equivalent to the first one or does the LIMIT in the second version only applies in the second `SELECT`? if so, what can i do to work around this? thanks (:

`ps: don't worry about the interrogation marks. that's just because of the prepared statements`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you don't need the the brackets:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM `users` 
 WHERE `access_level` > 0
   AND BINARY `username` = ?
UNION
SELECT * 
 FROM `users` 
WHERE `access_level` > 0
  AND BINARY `username` = ?
LIMIT 5
```

There's no difference in either side of the UNION to begin with, so there's no need for it.

No, the LIMIT applies to the result of all the UNION'd queries, as does the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: what if i use ORDER BY in each one of the selections? i just tried it here and there was no errors...

Comment: @hugo_leonardo: MySQL supports an ORDER BY (and LIMIT) in each UNION as long as it is within the brackets, containing a query that makes part of a UNION.  I don't know of other dbs that allow this.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming these are sample queries, as your `SELECT` statements are not only redundant but poorly formed.

However, to answer your original question, adding parenthesis creates an expression that changes the order of operations. Just as it would in mathematics. So the result of the expression in your first example does not support the LIMIT clause. However, the second, with the `UNION` statement, does.

Long story short, the parentheses make it a different statement and invalidates the `LIMIT`. You don't need them. It's subtle, but that's the problem.

Comment: Brackets allowing independent ORDER BY and LIMIT on a UNION is not order of operations

Comment: Yes. This was a generalization of what adding parenthesis does to an expression. It is accurate that order of operations does change an expression - think more `x OR y AND z` versus `(x OR y) AND z`.